# Task/future in Ruby

Tags: ruby, asynchronous

What is the idiomatic Ruby analog of a pattern that represents a potentially deferred asynchronous computation with the possibility to subscribe to its completion? i.e. something along the lines of .NET `System.Threading.Task`, or Python 3.x `concurrent.futures.future`.

Note that this does not necessarily imply multithreading - the actual implementation of the "future" object would just as likely use some other way of scheduling the work and obtaining result, and is out of scope of the question. The question concerns strictly with the API that is presented to the user of the object.

Comment: sounds like something backgroundrb might help with, check out: http://backgroundrb.rubyforge.org/workers/

does this involve a web stack (webserver? db? cache?) #hopingfor+100rep

Comment: @edwardsharp No, this does not involve a web stack. Well, it can, actually, but it is more generic than that - this is about API for asynchronous operations w/callbacks in particular, regardless of how exactly that asynchrony is actually implemented.

Comment: Great read, implements a naive future api, may help.  http://tx.pignata.com/2012/11/concurrency-patterns-in-ruby-futures.html

Comment: I recently wrote a promises library: https://github.com/cameron-martin/pure_promise. It's designed to work with asynchronous i/o with a reactor library like eventmachine, but is completely agnostic in that respect; It would work just as well by linking it up to a thread pool or whatever. It might be the kind of thing you're looking for.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure about vanilla Ruby, but EventMachine has [deferrables](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/EM%3a%3aDeferrable-and-EM.defer).

Also, check out [this article](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2010/10/01/an-introduction-to-eventmachine-and-how-to-avoid-callback-spaghetti/).

```
EM.run {
  detector = LanguageDetector.new("Sgwn i os yw google yn deall Cymraeg?")
  detector.callback { |lang| puts "The language was #{lang}" }
  detector.errback { |error| puts "Error: #{error}" }
}
```

Comment: If there is a lack of a standard pattern in core Ruby, I will indeed have to look at what various frameworks offer to see if a common pattern can be derived there. This is a good pointer - do you know of any other frameworks that have something similar?

Comment: @PavelMinaev: from the top of my head - no. But I'll think about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Fiber?

Fibers are primitives for implementing light weight cooperative concurrency in Ruby. Basically they are a means of creating code blocks that can be paused and resumed, much like threads. The main difference is that they are never preempted and that the scheduling must be done by the programmer and not the VM. [link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fiber.html)

Comment: This isn't about concurrency per se, more about asynchrony. Suppose that I already have a library that is _not_ written in Ruby, but which returns futures (e.g. it's a .NET library and it returns System.Threading.Task). I need to know how to best expose that in Ruby in a way that will look most natural to Ruby developers.

Comment: Fiber actually is not about concurrency, it's non-blocking model, i.e. asynchrony, like node.js. You can check the usage of this techonlogy in ruby framework http://postrank-labs.github.com/goliath/

Comment: I understand that. Still, so far as I can see, fibers are an all or nothing thing - i.e. if you don't control the implementation of some of the APIs involved, and they _don't_ use fibers, you can't really use them yourself because you simply won't have a fiber to yield to. I need something higher-level that abstracts over implementation specifics of asynchrony in any given case, and presents a universal common interface for any type of async operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a job queue like [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque)
Have coded some quick examples for pure ruby

1. by forking a child process

   ```
   rd, wr = IO.pipe

   p1 = fork do
     rd.close
     # sleep is for demonstration purpose only
     sleep 10
     # the forked child process also has a copy of the open file
     # handles, so we close the handles in both the parent and child
     # process
     wr.write "1"
     wr.close
   end

   wr.close

   puts "Process detaching | #{Time.now}"
   Process.detach(p1)
   puts "Woot! did not block | #{Time.now}"

   1.upto(10) do
     begin
       result = rd.read_nonblock(1)
     rescue EOFError
       break
     rescue Exception
       # noop
     end

     puts "result: #{result.inspect}"
     system("ps -ho pid,state -p #{p1}")
     sleep 2
   end

   rd.close

   __END__

   ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]
   Process detaching | 2012-02-28 17:05:49 +0530
   Woot! did not block | 2012-02-28 17:05:49 +0530
   result: nil
     PID STAT
    5231 S+  
   result: nil
     PID STAT
    5231 S+  
   result: nil
     PID STAT
    5231 S+  
   result: nil
     PID STAT
    5231 S+  
   result: nil
     PID STAT
    5231 S+  
   result: "1"
     PID STAT
   ```
2. by having a callback on a thread

   ```
   require 'thread'

   Thread.abort_on_exception = true

   module Deferrable
     def defer(&block)
       # returns a thread
       Thread.new do
         # sleep is for demonstration purpose only
         sleep 10

         val = block.call
         # this is one way to do it. but it pollutes the thread local hash
         # and you will have to poll the thread local value
         # can get this value by asking the thread instance
         Thread.current[:human_year] = val
         # notice that the block itself updates its state after completion
       end
     end
   end

   class Dog
     include Deferrable
     attr_accessor :age, :human_age
     attr_accessor :runner

     def initialize(age=nil)
       @age = age
     end

     def calculate_human_age_as_deferred!
       self.runner = defer do
         # can do stuff with the values here
         human_age = dog_age_to_human_age
         # and finally publish the final value
         after_defer { self.human_age = human_age }
         # return value of the block. used in setting the thread local
         human_age
       end
     end

     protected
     def dog_age_to_human_age
       (self.age / 7.0).round(2)
     end

     def after_defer(&block)
       block.call
     end
   end

   dog = Dog.new(8)
   dog.calculate_human_age_as_deferred!

   1.upto(10) do
     sleep 2
     puts "status: #{dog.runner.status} | human_age: #{dog.human_age.inspect}"
     break unless dog.runner.status
   end

   puts "== using thread local"

   dog = Dog.new(8)
   dog.calculate_human_age_as_deferred!

   1.upto(10) do
     sleep 2
     puts "status: #{dog.runner.status} | human_age: #{dog.runner[:human_year].inspect}"
     break unless dog.runner.status
   end

   __END__

   ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]
   status: sleep | human_age: nil
   status: sleep | human_age: nil
   status: sleep | human_age: nil
   status: sleep | human_age: nil
   status: false | human_age: 1.14
   == using thread local
   status: sleep | human_age: nil
   status: sleep | human_age: nil
   status: sleep | human_age: nil
   status: sleep | human_age: nil
   status: false | human_age: 1.14
   ```

---

threads consume less memory than forking a child process but forking is robust. An unhandled   error in a thread can bring down the whole system. while an unhandled error in a child process, will only bring down the child process

Other people have pointed out fibres and eventmachine (using EM::Deferrable and EM.defer) are another option

Fibres and threads need careful coding. code can be wrong in subtle ways.
Also fibres use pre-emptive multitasking so the codebase has to be well behaved

Eventmachine is fast but it is an exclusive world (like twisted in python). It has its own separate IO stack, so all the libraries have to be written to support eventmachine.  Having said that, i do not think library support is a problem for eventmachine

Comment: I am not implementing asynchrony, I am exposing something that is already implemented to Ruby. "The question concerns strictly with the API that is presented to the user of the object."

Comment: @PavelMinaev if i get the comment correctly. you want a non-invasive solution? both the solutions are a little invasive. For the example i gave, will have to use a wrapper around the code. Can always make a gem out of it

Comment: Imagine that I have a DLL, written in C, that exposes an asynchronous function. Asynchrony is in the form of a callback - i.e. you call it, and provide your callback that is called once the operation is done. How exactly that is implemented is an implementation detail - the DLL can use threads or fibers or something else. I need to wrap and expose said function to Ruby code in some way that is idiomatic for Ruby, but I cannot touch its implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but if the situation is as you describe in your response to deepak, then why not wrap the C API as a Ruby extension and provide a Ruby method that accepts a block corresponding to your needed callback?  That would also be very idiomatic Ruby.

Here's a sample chapter dealing with extending Ruby with C from the "Pickaxe" Book updated for Ruby 1.9: http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf.

**Update:**
Here are some links dealing with Ruby exceptions in Ruby and in it's C interface.

- http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html
- http://clalance.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-ruby-extensions-in-c-part-5.html
- http://clalance.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-ruby-extensions-in-c-part-6.html

Comment: It is a possibility, if that's the standard way of doing things. It still invites some further questions, e.g. if result is propagated to the callback as its argument, then how should errors (exceptions) be propagated?

Comment: You could do this the same way you would for any Ruby library by throwing an exception. This could be done in C as the Ruby C interface allows you to basically do anything you can in Ruby in C (read more verbosely), or it could be done in a Ruby wrapper.  I'll update my answer with some links on Ruby exceptions in and out of the C interface.

Comment: Since the function executes asynchronously, any error/exception it would throw would also be reported asynchronously. I.e. when you call it as `foo({|result| ... })`, it can't throw an exception at the point of the call, because it hasn't started executing yet. Rather, it needs to propagate that exception to the callback. Passing it as an additional parameter, i.e. `foo({|result, err| ... })` is one option. Another is passing a promise instead of raw result, i.e. `foo({|promise| result = promise.result ... })`, and then `promise.result` would throw if there was an error.

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have mentioned throwing an exception.  I do like the `foo {|result, err| ... }` type callback it's very jQuery-ish, which would be familiar to many Ruby programmers.  Also, EventMachine has an `error_handler` callback that catches all errors that result from the event loop, which may work for you too. (see http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine.html#M000496)

Answer (score 1):

[lazy.rb](http://moonbase.rydia.net/software/lazy.rb/) provides "futures", but they don't seem to be exactly the same as you describe (or I would expect):

> Additionally, the library provides futures, where a computation is run immediately in a background thread.

So, you can't compute them later, or insert values into them (from the network perhaps) by other means.

Comment: It's still a good pointer - even if those things have hardcoded implementation, looking at their API surface is useful. Unfortunately, they look really simplistic; specifically, there's no way to subscribe to completion of the future there, you can only block until it gives you a result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by subscribe; do you mean like this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx

Comment: Yes, pretty much that. Not necessarily chainable like that, though - e.g. see `Future.add_done_callback` in standard module `concurrent.futures` in Python 3.x.

Comment: You could simulate that by spawning a new thread to wait on the future and execute the callback after, although obviously there's a lot of unnecessary overhead there.  There is also no documented way to tell if a future's value has been computed yet (although it looks like inspect could be used; I'm no rubyist), and no thread pooling or computation queueing; each future seems to be computed in its own new thread.

Comment: I wouldn't use these particular futures anyway; to remind, I already _have_ an equivalent of a future from a different language, and how it is implemented is not under my control.My goal is to expose that equivalent of a future in a way that's idiomatic Ruby - so if Ruby (or some popular third-party library) already has futures or their equivalent, I'd try to use them (not an option here, as these things convert an existing sync function to async; I already have async), or else imitate them.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be extremely helpful:

https://github.com/wireframe/backgrounded

It is a gem that simply allows pushing methods onto a background task.

Answer (score 1):

The [thread](https://rubygems.org/gems/thread) gem might be of interest. You can make a thread-pool that processes stuff in the background. The gem also support a whole lot of other features like future, delay etc. Have a look at [the github repo](https://github.com/meh/ruby-thread).

It appears to work with a wide range of ruby versions, not just 1.9+, which is why I use this.