# Detect method call

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to implement lazy method execution in ruby. Let's say I have a class with two methods which should not be executed immediately after call

```
class Foo
  lazy_evaluate :bar, :baz

  def bar(string)
    puts string
  end

  def baz(hash)
    puts hash.inspect
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar('hello world') => nil
f.baz(hello: :world) => nil

f.run_lazy_methods =>
'hello world'
'{:hello=>:world}'
```

I wan't use this in my gem http://pastie.org/5137463

I'm asking for idea how to implement this behaviour

Comment: Look at Delayed Job, Sidekiq, or any of the other asynchronous queuing gems.

Comment: Imo in this specific case I can't use Delayed job and other background workers. http://pastie.org/5137463

Comment: You may want to take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371875/task-future-in-ruby

Comment: I'm telling you to look at them for inspiration, not to actually use them.

Answer (score 3):

Use a delegate object, record the methods invoked onto a stack, then replay them on the delegate.

```
class LazyObject
  def initialize(delegate)
    @invocations = []
    @delegate    = delegate
  end

  def bar(*args, &block)
    @invocations << {
      method: :bar,
      args:   args,
      block:  block
    }
  end

  def baz(*args, &block)
    @invocations << {
      method: :baz,
      args:   args,
      block:  block
    }
  end

  def run_lazy_methods
    @invocations.each do |inv|
      @delegate.send(
        inv[:method],
        *inv[:args],
        &inv[:block]
      )
    end
  end
end

obj = LazyObject.new(RealObject.new)
obj.bar(hello: :world)
obj.baz("Hello World")
obj.run_lazy_methods
```

You could write the above better using `method_missing`, but I wanted to make it clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found it difficult to make it possible to allow `lazy_evaluate` before the corresponding method definitions. My implementation works when you put it after the corresponding definitions.

The preparation part is:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @queue = []
  end
  def run_lazy_methods
    @queue.each{|proc| proc.call}
  end
  def self.lazy_evaluate *methods
    methods.each do |method|
      alias :"old_#{method}" :"#{method}"
      define_method method do |*args, &pr|
        @queue.push(->{send(:"old_#{method}", *args, &pr)})
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, when you define the methods, and call `lazy_evaluate`, they become lazy.

```
class Foo
  def bar(string)
    puts string
  end
  def baz(hash)
    puts hash.inspect
  end

  lazy_evaluate :bar, :baz
end
```

And you will get the expected results.

```
f = Foo.new
f.bar('hello world')
f.baz(hello: :world)
f.run_lazy_methods
```

Comment: Put the lazy_methods definition in a module. Use [`method_added`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-method_added) to capture the method definitions as they are inserted.

Comment: @d11wtq Is that for moving the `lazy_evaluation` to the front of `foo`, and `baz` definitions?

Comment: sawa that's right, yes. If you have a list of method names that you want to wrap, you can detect when they get defined because as each one is defined, method_added is invoked, so you can wrap them at the point.